# categorical variable panel ols

Tags: pandas, statsmodels, panel-data

For my PanelOLS i like to include categorical variables. 
This is my model:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

exog_vars = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']
exog = sm.add_constant(df[exog_vars])
mod = PanelOLS(df.y, exog, entity_effects=True, time_effects=True)
result = mod.fit(cov_type='clustered', cluster_entity=True)
```

The categorial variable is a number for a industry. This nummber is stored in my dataframe(`df['x4']`). 
Do you know how to include categorical variables? Or do you need more information to answer the question.

My dataframe:
[image]

I tried:

```
df['x4'] = pd.Categorical(gesamt.x4)

mod = PanelOLS(gesamt.CAR, exog, other_effects=df['x4'], entity_effects=True, time_effects=True)
```

The follwing error occured:

> ```
> raise ValueError('At most two effects supported.')
> ```
>
> ValueError: At most two effects supported.

Comment: Are `x1`, `x2`, `x3` numerical?

Comment: yes, all columns are nummerical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is probably to one-hot-encode your column `x4`.

If you have

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [1,2,3], 'x4': ['bob', 'cat' ,'cat']})
df
```

which looks like

```
   x1   x4
0   1  bob
1   2  cat
2   3  cat
```

then

```
pd.get_dummies(df, 'x4')
```

gives you

```
   x1  x4_bob  x4_cat
0   1       1       0
1   2       0       1
2   3       0       1
```

Alternatively,

```
df['x4'] = pd.Categorical(df.x4).codes
df
```

will give you

```
   x1  x4
0   1   0
1   2   1
2   3   1
```

Comment: thank you for your solution. In my case i have about 100 diffrent industries. Do you know if there is another way than to create new columns for every industrie

Comment: Can you put an example of your data in your question? Not sure I understand, sorry

Comment: @Pytno I've updated my answer - perhaps this is what you're after?

Comment: (As an aside, if you use `LightGBM` as your model, then you can use categorical columns directly without needing to encode them)